# Why does max-width in this case not work

Tags: css

Why does max-width in the following example not work?

http://jsfiddle.net/uvbfo8np/

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>blah</label>
            <div>
                <input />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

```
input {
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
form {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

To see what I mean make the right window smaller then 1000px (so that the input is bigger then the window), then switch the width of the input to 100% and see that it fits now.

What I want to archive: The input shall be 1000px wide, but not wider as the screen (or in jsfidde the frame).

As someone said in the comments the parent does not got any width. But at least the form element got a width (set with max-width). And normaly that works. The problem here is the `fieldset`. Remove the fieldset from the code and it works.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the width of parent element of the input ? If the width is greater that less than 1000px, thus the input get that that max-width ?

Max-width can only know what width the element can have at max. giving 100% will not let it know which value to be giving to the element width parameter. 

Here width:100% tells that the width of input is the width of the parent element and thus when you write : width:100% and max-width:100% it will work. here also I would ignore max-width.

Comment: @Guy That everything is width: 100% and not wider. Is it not clear? Shall I update the question?

Comment: If you want everything to have width:100%, simply give width:100% and don't use max-width. It doesn't make sense using max-width in this case

Comment: Well what your current code says is that you want the input to be 1000px, or 100%, whichever is greater. `max-width: 100%` means the element will never be wider than the width of its parent.

Comment: @VivekTankaria This case is an example. The question is, why is max-width ignored

Comment: @Guy I understand that. And when I set width: 100% it says the width is the same as its parent. So why width works but max-width not? Just change width of the input to 100% to see what I mean

Comment: Width takes the value of parent element when you set it to 100%. It calculates and assign . But in case of Max-width it doesn't calculate what width the parent element has. Thus it fails to assign it. % doesn't work in max-width only px works. Give a hard code 500px to max-width it will take. give 50% or 60% It will not take the value. Thus it will be ignored

Comment: There is no fixed width on the parent so takes the width of the element (1000px), thus the `max-width: 100%` is `1000px`. Does that make sense? If you set a width of `500px` on the form, the `max-width` will be applied

Comment: @VivekTankaria > "% doesn't work in max-width only px works." That is totally untrue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

After some inspecting I found a default browser CSS for fieldset;

```
  min-width: -webkit-min-content;
```

Just add the following to get your desired result;

```
fieldset {
    min-width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for, I didn't see the min-width set by the browser!

Comment: This isn't enough to fix the problem in Firefox. You must also apply `display: table-cell` to the `<fieldset>`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies with the `<fieldset>`. They are a pain in the a** to reset, and in Webkit and Gecko they're always as wide as their widest child, ignoring `max-width`.

You can override this behaviour in Webkit with `min-width: 0`, but Firefox doesn't allow authors to edit it.

The only solution to this that I'm aware of is to set the `display` property of the `<fieldset>` to `table-cell`. It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: I allready acepted an answer, but damn you are right, overwrite min-width of the fieldset does not work in firefox. Thanks for the hint with table-cell. That works (and yes it's ugly). Hope you get upvotes cause your answer provides more information.

Answer (score -3):

you can't set the dynamic value( means value in % ) to 'max-width' for this you need to give fixed value.
you can give that kind of value to width

It's my point of view.

Comment: [try checking documentation before posting wildly incorrect answers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).